# How to write If Else in Typescript Push method

Tags: javascript

I have a push method where I am pushing some key-value pairs.
I want to write an `if-else condition`.I want to set the value of `categories`(after 'key': row[0], 'value': row[1]) using an If-else condition and not hardcode it as general-settings.
Is it possible. If yes then how?

```
Object.entries(this.generalInfoForm.value).forEach((row, index) => {
console.log(this.finalObject.properties);
  // index < 5 ? this.finalObject.properties.push({ 'key': row[0], 'value': row[1], 'categories': objMap[row[0]] }) : '';
  index < 5 ? this.finalObject.properties.push({
    'key': row[0], 'value': row[1], 'categories': 'general-settings'
  }) : '';
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a plain `if` instead of the ternary operator?

Comment: I think you don't need a ternary if-else statement

Comment: typically ternary operators are best for assignments, not doing if statements.

Answer (score 3):

Don't overthink it. Just determine the `categories` value ahead of time and use that:

```
Object.entries(this.generalInfoForm.value).forEach((row, index) => {
    console.log(this.finalObject.properties);

    if (index < 5) {
        const categories =
            condition
                ? trueValue
                : falseValue;

        this.finalObject.properties.push({
            'key': row[0],
            'value': row[1],
            categories,
        });
    }
});
```

If you reeeeeally wanted to combine it into the object creation expression, of course you could, but I wouldn't recommend it as it's deleterious to readability:

```
this.finalObject.properties.push({
    'key': row[0],
    'value': row[1],
    'categories': condition ? trueValue : falseValue,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value for categories is in `row[3]` and if not existing or empty you want it to be 'general-settings' you would do the following:

```
Object.entries(this.generalInfoForm.value).forEach((row, index) => {
  if (index > 5) {
    this.finalObject.properties.push({
      'key': row[0], 
      'value': row[1], 
      'categories': (row[3] && row[3] !== '') ? row[3] : 'general-settings'
    })
  }
});
```